# Dynamically populate dropdown list in Concrete5

Tags: concrete5

I have a list of pages with attribute "region", like:

```
Page1 region = Montreal
Page2 region = Montreal
Page3 region = Quebec
Page4 region = Quebec
Page5 region = Charlevoix
```

I would like to dynamically populate the dropdown list with only regions where I have a page like:

```
<select>
<option value="1">Montreal</option>
<option value="2">Quebec</option>
<option value="3">Charlevoix</option>
</select>
```

I do this, but I have problem building the query:

```
$db = Loader::db();
$ak_locations = CollectionAttributeKey::getByHandle('region');
$r = $db->Execute("SELECT DISTINCT ....);
```

Comment: what is your table schema look like? Also, it should be Québec / Montréal no?

Comment: Thank you Karel for your answer, but the problem, I do not know the scheme of the table because I use Concrete5 (cms), if you want to add a new field (called attribute), you can do it in the backend. My concern is to filter with the attribute I added.

Answer (score 0):

I already answered you on concrete5.org but maybe you didn't see the answer so here goes:

if you look in the select attribute's controller (concrete/attributes/select/controller.php) around line 541, you will see a function getOptionUsageArray()

I think this is your best bet. You can either use that function and filter through the result to remove options with zero use. Or you can have a look at the SQL query they're using to adapt it to your need.

One way you could modify it is by making sure it doesn't return any result with zero use so you don't have to filter it afterward.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Nour,

I did this and it's work :

```
$reg = CollectionAttributeKey::getByHandle('Region');
$options = $reg->getController()->getOptionUsageArray();
if (!empty($options)) {
    print("<Select>");
    foreach($options as $option) {
         printf("<option value=\"%s\">%s</option>", $option->getSelectAttributeOptionDisplayValue(), $option->getSelectAttributeOptionDisplayValue());
    }
    print("</Select>");
}
```